# Finding the inverse of a 2x2 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Use the given information to find A.

```
(I-5A^T)^-1 =   -1, -1
                 4,  5
```

I did it like this:

A ^ -1 =   1/ (-1)(5)-(-1)(4)

I-5A = 1/-1  {5    2}
             {-4  -1}

I - 5A =   {-5    -2}        {1 0}
          {-1/5  -1/1}   +   {1 0}

(1/5) 5A = {-4 -2}    (1/5)
           {1/4 0}

a = {-20  -10}
    {5/4   0}

I would like to know if I'm doing it correctly, please forgive me if I formatted the matrix wrong. Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: I can't follow what you are doing. What do the curly braces {} represent, and in the first part why have you said $A^{-1}=\frac{1}{-1\cdot5-(-1\cdot 4)}$, when the left hand side is a matrix and the right hand side is is a number?

Answer (score 1):

There's lots to like here, but lots wrong as well.

First, to format stuff, look here: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Your first line says that $A^{-1}$ is $1 / (-1)$, but that's not true; that's the inverse of the determinant of the matrix on the right. Let's call that matrix on the right $B$.

You need to find $B^{-1}$, so finding 1 over its determinant is a good first step. In the end, you should get 
$$
B^{-1} = \frac{1}{-1} \begin{bmatrix} 5 & 1 \\ -4 & -1\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} -5 & -1 \\ 4 & 1\end{bmatrix}.
$$

(What you actually got has a $2$ in it for some reason, which is part of what went wrong in the rest of your answer.)

And that, i.e., $B^{-1}$, is the matrix that must be $I - 5A^{t}$. Perhaps you can work things out from there.